# How can I make this jBox gallery responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design, jbox

I have this [page](http://antonio-p-ortiz.com/work/) (that still is a work in progress) which houses some thumbnails of images which will pop open a larger version when clicked; I am using [jBox](http://stephanwagner.me/jBox) to accomplish this. I am trying to get that larger image to behave in a responsive manner. But can't get anything to work!

I checked via the inspector and it appears this is the container `#jBoxID2`; And I guess I'd only need it below the breakpoint below because i am really just concerned with mobile, phablet and tablet!

```
@media all and (max-width: 560px) {
   #jBoxID2{
     width: 90%;
     position:absolute!important;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Added image of container for clarity!
[image]

**UPDATE Mar 2nd**

I believe I may be close, but can't get that inner image to position inside the container! I haven't uploaded the code in the repo, so if you check that out it wont be updated yet. I'll upload it later!

[image]

```
#jBoxID2{
    position: absolute!important;
    margin: auto!important;
    right: 0!important;
    left: 0!important;
    max-width: 500px!important;
    padding-top: 10px!important;
    padding-left:10px!important;
    padding-right:10px!important;
  }

 .jBox-image-container{
   margin: 0 auto!important;
   max-width: 480px!important;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the right selector? When I looked it up for id `jBoxID2` in the source code I couldn't find such id. You should double check it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Indeed. The above is a screenshot of dev-tools, showing the id/classes for the element.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit tired and didn't noticed the thumbnails were injected after the page loads. :) Anyway, I looked it up and while you can change #jBoxID2 width, there are two things to keep in mind:
1. It has a left of 50% which pushes the div right
2. The image itself is fixed on width of 500px, so whatever change you make on that jBoxID2 div, it changes its background but not the image of it. So you have to modify the image to set it to max-width of 500px, or alternatively use percentage. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, for your insight, I recently updated my css, see above updates (but not the actual site), I'll do that later...If you have a moment I'd appreciate your thoughts! - cheers!

Comment: Hey Antonio, that was exactly my point. :) The image itself is 500px wide, therefore it shrinks the background div which is flexible, and yet the image remains fixed on 500px. Change the image px's to percentages and you'll see the magic. :)

Comment: Notice that there are two boxes in dynamic, and the background box does not reflect the changes on the image, although the image is a child element of that div.